# javascript simple addition computation

Tags: javascript, html, addition, computation

im new to javascript. i dont know what's wrong with my code

```
num1:<input id="num1" type="number">
num2:<input id="num2" type="number">

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">compute</button>

answer:<input id="demo" type="text"> and answer: <p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    var ans = x + y;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ans;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` on the numbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562260/javascript-simple-addition-program-not-working/32562296#32562296

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use an ID twice in an document and the values you get from the input fields are strings and **you do an string addition, so you have to parse it to integer before**. The HTML5 input type `number` onlys displays in some new browsers a field which is invalid for other characters than numbers, but you get a string when you read the value of it with javascript.
You can parse your strings with `parseInt`. If you want to support float, you can use `parseFloat`.

```
num1:<input id="num1" type="number">
num2:<input id="num2" type="number">

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">compute</button>

answer:<input id="demoInput" type="text"> and answer: <p id="demoHtml"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    var ans = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y)
    document.getElementById("demoInput").value = ans;
    document.getElementById("demoHtml").innerHTML = ans;
}
</script>
```

By the way:
If you want to name two or more elements with the same ID, use the class attribute. And you get with `document.getElementsByClassName("demo")` an array of your elements.

Comment: This does not answer the basic problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer ...

```
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">compute</button>

answer:<input id="demo" type="text"> and answer: <p id="demo"></p>

<script> function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("num2").value;  
    var ans = parseInt(x) + parseInt(y);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ans; }
</script>
```

Comment: the reason is given by @pavelDurov

Comment: My question was rhetorical. For an answer to be complete, it needs to not only give code, but explain **why** and **how** the code solves the problem. Referring to another answer to the explanation doesn't really qualify.

Answer (score 0):

You have the id="demo" twice. In case of input there is no innerHtml, it is value instead but thats not what you want. So use this:

```
    document.querySelector("p#demo").innerHTML = ans;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get value from an input control you will get it as String type , even thought you set it as number type in html - this type is for text input restrictions only (you can enter only numbers to that textbox).

```
var ans = x + y;
```

Here you've simply "chained" the x and y strings to a new variable - that's what '+' operator does when used on strings.

- You can notice strings by " symbol which surrounds them while numbers aren't...

Parsing (deserialization) of string objects to numbers can be done with parseFloat (converts to float type) and parseInt (converts to int type).

Also, you can check types ether by instanceof or with constructor:

```
if(ans.constructor === String){

}
```